# For Loop C# issue

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to implement a simple loop that keeps iterating until the value of 200 is reached.

But where i have i= the initial value i want it to pull using the following XPath `string totalPrice = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='bag-subtotal-price']")).Text;` so  i won't actually have a value set it will be dynamic depending on the item.

I then want to increment the loop by increasing the quantity of the bag till it reaches the 200.

To increase the value of quantity i need to use the following XPaths

```
 IWebElement qty = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(
   "//select[contains(@class,'bag-item-quantity')]"));

 SelectElementFromDropDown(qty, Math.Floor(noOfQuantity).ToString());

 wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath(
   "//button[@class='bag-item-edit-update']")));

 webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(
   "//button[@class='bag-item-edit-update']")).Click();
```

Is there there a way i can call the values from the XPaths instead of hard coding them?

```
 public void Main()
 {
     for (int i = 120; i <= 200; i++)
     {
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a `while` loop instead:

```
string strTotalPrice = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='bag-subtotal-price']")).Text;

int totalPrice = Convert.ToInt32(strTotalPrice);

while(totalPrice <= 200)
{
    // whatever code that increases totalPrice's value
}
```